# Is \xHH character representation obsoleted after z3 4.8.11?

Tags: z3

I've found the following code results `sat` and `unsat` in `z3@4.8.10` and `z3@4.8.11`, respectively.

```
(assert (= (str.len "\x4a") 1))
(check-sat)
```

I think this is because of the change in 4.8.11 for unicode default support.

Now the question is:

- is there a switch to back the previous behavior?
- (if not) is "\u{HH}" the proper representation for non-ascii characters?

Edit:
I've noticed usual escape sequences (like "\n") also cannot be used.  It would be more inconvenient...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct. Z3 now supports the new SMTLib string theory, documented here:

http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-UnicodeStrings.shtml

So far as I know, there's no "switch to previous behavior" switch.

Your specific question about escape sequences is answered in the above document. For reference, here's what it says:

> The restriction to printable US ASCII characters in string constants
> is for    simplicity since that set is universally supported.
> Arbitrary Unicode characters    can be represented with *escape
> sequences* which can have one of the following forms
>
> ```
>   \ud₃d₂d₁d₀  
>   \u{d₀} 
>   \u{d₁d₀}
>   \u{d₂d₁d₀}
>   \u{d₃d₂d₁d₀}
>   \u{d₄d₃d₂d₁d₀}
> ```
>
> where each dᵢ is a hexadecimal digit and d₄ is restricted to the range 0-2.
>
> These are the **only escape sequences**
> in this theory. See later.   In a later version, the restrictions
> above on the digits may be extended    to allow characters from all 17
> Unicode planes.
> Observe that the first form, \ud₃d₂d₁d₀, has exactly 4 hexadecimal digit,    following the common use of this form in some programming
> languages.   Unicode characters outside the range covered by
> \ud₃d₂d₁d₀ can be   represented with the long form \u{d₄d₃d₂d₁d₀}.
>
> Also observe that programming language-specific escape sequences, such as   \n, \b, \r and so on, are *not* escape sequences in this
> theory as they   are not fully standard across languages.

As it explicitly states in the last paragraph, sequences such as `\n`, `\r` etc are **not** valid and won't be interpreted as an escape sequence at all. Instead, you should use `\u{a}` for `\n`, etc., since the ASCII code for `\n` is 10.